# Flutter Firestore stream list docs to list model more efficient method

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have a list of documents in firestore. When the user adds a new document I would like to update the document list as models. I have this working but it seems like a bad method.

I get the stream like this:

```
  Stream buildingsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('buildings').snapshots();
```

Then I create an empty list of BuildingModel. I do a forEach on the stream, add convert each document in the stream to BuildingModel and add it to the list. Finally, I update the value of the List of building model with the new list. Like this:

```
 Stream buildingsStream = _firestoreApi.buildingsStream;

 buildingsStream.listen((result) {
   List<BuildingModel> buildings = [];
   result.docs.forEach((document) => buildings.add(BuildingModel.fromJson(document.data())));
   _buildings.value = buildings;
 });
```

This is obviously not the best way to do it. Every time I add a single value, it does a for loop through the whole stream and updates with a new list.

How can I do this better?

Thanks

Comment: you could only use `result.docs.last` but what if a value is modified or deleted? btw how long is `result.docs`? do you have 100s values, 1000s, more?

Comment: 100s maximum length

Comment: Yes they can be deleted

Comment: so you have to iterate over `result.docs` - there is no other way